# Android - OnActivityResult() resultCode is 0 and Intent is empty on Camera Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, onactivityresult

I'm developing an Android App that uses an `Intent` to open the in-built camera, and take a photo that then should be saved to storage and be sent to a different intent that crops it.

I've run the app a few times but can't see any of the photos being saved anywhere in storage. I started debugging the code and found that it was skipping out on the commands in the `OnActivityResult` method because the `resultCode` parameter was always going back as 0.
Out of curiosity I manually changed this to the required value of -1, and the code then skipped out on the next if statement because `data.getExtras()` (`data` being the Intent parameter) was returning null, even though I had been adding an extra in the code that triggered the Camera Activity.

I can't quite figure out what's happening here. I'd assume the image is saving somehow because no exception is being thrown, but don't see what might be causing the empty values of `resultCode` and `data`.

My code is shown below. If anyone can give me a point in the right direction, that would be a massive help!

Thanks,
Mark

```
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            if (optionItems[i].equals(OPTION_CAMERA)) {
                //intent to open device camera
                Intent cameraIntent =
                        new Intent(
                                MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE
                        );

                //create 'Spond' folder inside photo directory
                //target folder for image to be saved
                File imagesFolder =
                        new File(
                                Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                                        Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
                                getString(R.string.app_name)
                        );
                //create directory if it doesn't already exist
                imagesFolder.mkdirs(); //bool return value not needed

                //create file with unique id
                File image = createFileAtUniquePath(imagesFolder);
                //use authority for AndroidManifest to create permission
                //to get uri from temporary file in app
                String fileProviderAuthority = getApplicationContext().getPackageName() +
                        getString(R.string.authorities_fileprovider);
                Uri uriSavedImage = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                        getApplicationContext(),
                        fileProviderAuthority,
                        image
                );

                //pass URI to intent so it will be available in activity result
                cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage);
                //grant read/write permissions with file
                cameraIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                cameraIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
```

The `OnActivityResult` code:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA) {
            if (data.getExtras() != null) {
                newAccountPhotoUri = (Uri) data.getExtras().get(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT);
                newAccountPhotoFileName = getFileNameFromURI(newAccountPhotoUri);
                if (!newAccountPhotoFileName.equals("")) {
                    appAccountPhotoChanged = true;
                    //send image to be cropped
                    cropImage(newAccountPhotoUri);
                }
            }
        }
        //...
    }
```

Comment: where is code of onActivityResult?

Comment: @ZaidMirza it got missed off the initial copy & paste. You can see it now.

Comment: you said in question that you are changing resultCode value, but I can't see it in your code. However if result code is 0 then it means Camera activity sending result as if user cancel the task